# Patch assembly and nuget version of each project independently

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, azure-devops

I have a solution with multiple projects (each is a nuget package for some common utils).

I want to build all these projects in VSTS.

The problem each project has a unique version.

1. `version.txt` file is stored in each project's folder, and contains the version in format `x.x.x`
2. before build each project should be patched with this version
3. build and push nuget packages

VSTS contains task `dotnet build` which can build an entire solution or a concrete project. But I need to automate this process - once the new project was added it should be built automatically.

I didn't find the ready-to-use build task which can read the file and patch all parameters of csproj (FileVersion, AssemblyVersion, Version, PackageVersion), and do this per project.

It would be great to have this version.txt file to have a single point of configuration (instead of changing all the parameters)

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find the ready-to-use build task which can read the file and
>   patch all parameters of csproj (FileVersion, AssemblyVersion, Version,
>   PackageVersion), and do this per project

Actually, you can get AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyVersion easily by related task (such as **[Assembly Info Reader task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kherzog.AssemblyInfoReader)**).

You just need to specify the path for `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, then you can get the AssemblyFileVersion by the variable `$(ASSEMBLYINFO.ASSEMBLYFILEVE)`, and get the AssemblyVersion by the variable `$(ASSEMBLYINFO.ASSEMBLYVERSION)`. And you can use the version for the package.

**BTW:** the packed packages use it's AssemblyVersion by default. So if you want to packages use their AssemblyVersions, there is no need to do additional settings.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the solution so invented a new bicycle.

1. In each project folder there is a `version.txt` file with the version of exact package
2. Powershell scripts finds all `version.txt` files and uses the version from the file to patch `.csproj` file (package, assembly, whatever)
3. build all projects
4. In my scenario I don't want to add build number to the version so I have packages with the same version over builds. So I want to skip already exist packages

With Powershell script I do `nuget list <package name>` to check whether package already exists.

If not - pushing it to the repository.

Comment: Why you patches .csproj through PowerShell? About push logic nothing is said in the question.

Comment: I didn't find a built-in task in VSTS which can read the version from the file and patch per project. please read #3 in a question - it's about to push the package